# Podemos permutar as palavras de "trabalho só amanhã" a bel-prazer?

Tags: ordem-de-expressões

Abstract: can we change the word order in "trabalho só amanhã"?

As três palavras de "trabalho só amanhã" podem ser permutadas de seis maneiras diferentes:

> (a) Trabalho só amanhã
>   (b) Trabalho amanhã só
>   (c) Só trabalho amanhã
>   (d) Só amanhã trabalho
>   (e) Amanhã trabalho só
>   (f) Amanhã só trabalho

Quais destas frases são gramaticalmente corretas? A reordenação altera o significado?

Comment: Acho que se não fosse em inglês, [esta resposta](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157) seria a melhor.

Comment: @Jacinto as opções acima são frases singulares ou usos dessas 3 palavras? Surgiu essa dúvida devido ao comentário do Artefacto na minha resposta.

Comment: As frases são mesmo aquelas. Introduzindo mais palavras pode alterar os significados possíveis. Parece-me no entanto legítimo explorar possíveis significados das frases na sequência de outras.

Comment: It's the Portuguese counterpart to "She only drives to work on Fridays"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temos dois casos principais, ou *só* qualifica *amanhã* (i.e. amanhã em exlusão de outros dias), ou *só* qualifica *trabalho* (i.e. trabalhar em exclusão de outras atividades).

> (a) Trabalho só amanhã.
>   (b) Trabalho amanhã só.
>   (c) Só trabalho amanhã.

Duas interpretações possíveis:

1. Trabalharei amanhã, não hoje ou noutros dias. Afirmação de facto, sem mais.
2. Era expectável que trabalhasse noutros dias, mas na verdade, só o hei de fazer amanhã.

(b) é possível, mas pouco natural.

(c) é a mais problemática de analisar. Pela ordem parecia que *só* qualifica *trabalho*, mas na verdade é difícil interpretá-la como "amanhã só trabalho" (seria preciso uma pronunciar juntos "só trabalho", e mesmo assim não soaria muito natural). De resto, parece-me até um pouco mais natural do que (a).

> (d) Só amanhã trabalho.

Neste caso é mais difícil interpretar como (1). Diria portanto apenas a podemos interpretar como (2), uma forma menos natural de "só amanhã **é que** trabalho".

> (e) Amanhá trabalho só.
>   (f) Amanhã só trabalho.

Não faço outras coisas. A segunda é bastante mais natural.

Uma outra hipótese é *só* significar *sozinho*. Este caso não é muito interessante (nem sequer é provável que as frases sejam entendidas dessa forma por esse valor de *só* é incomum na oralidade), mas em todo o caso aí as frases significariam sempre o mesmo. No entanto, as únicas com uma ordem normal são:

> (a) Trabalho só amanhã.
>   (b) Trabalho amanhã só.
>   (e) Amanhã trabalho só.

Ou seja, *só* tem de vir depois do verbo. O resto são anástrofes. A mais natural é (e).

Comment: A (a), (b) e (e) não poderiam ter o significado de "Eu trabalho sozinho amanhã."? A (c) "Só trabalho amanhã e depois vou de férias."? A (d) parece-me estranha. E a (e) "Amanhã só trabalho, não vou fazer pausas."?

Comment: @JorgeB. 1) usar "só" por "sozinho" seria muito incomum na oralidade, eu interpreto sempre "só" como _somente_ / _apenas_; 2) Acho que todas que (a) (e (b), embora essa seja pouco natural) podem ser interpretadas assim; esse sentido pode ser colapsado em "amanhã e não noutros dias"; 3) concordo, seria mais natural adicional *é que*; 4) de novo, esse sentido pode ser incluído em "tabalhar em exlcusão de outras atividades".

Comment: @JorgeB Também gostaria de ver explorada a possibilidade de _só_ significando _sozinho_. Ser pouco comum na linguagem coloquial não me parece uma boa razão para exclusão.

Comment: @Jacinto Adicionei qualquer coisa.

Comment: "amanhã trabalho só" soa como "trabaho sozinho" aos meus ouvidos brasileiros.

Comment: @Centaurus Possível, mas acho que "amanhã trabalho só" quer com "só" a significar sozinho, quer com "só" a significar "somente" seriam difíceis de se encontrar. Ou se diria "amanhã trabalho sozinho" ou "amanhã só trabalho".

Comment: No Brazil "estou só" é talvez mais comum do que "estou sozinho".

Comment: A resposta é interessante, mas perdi-me um bocado bela. Ficaria mais clara se em vez de ir de significado em significado possível, fosses de frase em frase, indicando para cada os significados possíveis e, se mais do que um, se um é mais natural, imediato que outro.

Comment: @Jacinto Pensei nisso, mas a minha ideia foi de que uma resposta que fosse simplesmente de frase em frase perderia a noção de todo.

Comment: O problema do teu método é que não é fácil de ver se uma frase é ambígua ou não, ou qual seria a melhor (por ser menos ambígua) para exprimir uma ideia.

Answer (score 5):

Pelo que me parece todas as opções são válidas gramaticalmente falando, dependendo apenas do contexto em que estão inseridas. Claro que em termos de significado podem ser diferentes.

Ficam alguns exemplos de como podem ser empregues as expressões.

#### (a) Trabalho só amanhã

> Quando vais de férias? Trabalho só amanhã e depois vou de férias.
>
> Com quem trabalhas amanhã? Trabalho só, amanhã.<sup>1</sup>

#### (b) Trabalho amanhã só

> Quando vais de férias? Trabalho amanhã só e depois vou de férias.

#### (c) Só trabalho amanhã

> Quando vais de férias? Só trabalho amanhã e depois vou de férias.

#### (d) Só amanhã trabalho

> Quantas horas trabalhas esta semana? Só amanhã trabalho 12 horas!

#### (e) Amanhã trabalho só

> Quantas horas trabalhas esta semana? Amanhã trabalho só 6 horas e depois trabalho 12 horas todos os dias.
>
> Com quem trabalhas amanhã? Amanhã trabalho só.<sup>1</sup>

#### (f) Amanhã só trabalho

> Quantas horas trabalhas esta semana? Amanhã só trabalho 6 horas e depois trabalho 12 horas todos os dias.

---

Nos três primeiros casos fica a ideia que "trabalho amanhã e não em outros dias" como já tinha dito o @Artefacto, embora a (c) me parece perfeitamente natural.

No caso da (d) pode ser entendido como um exagero do que vou fazer amanhã, no meu exemplo.

As duas últimas podem ser entendidas como amanhã tenho de trabalhar apenas 6 horas.

Quis colocar estes exemplos porque alguns deles como é o caso do (d), (e) e (f) nada têm a ver com a interpretação do @Artefacto. Por isso é que acho que depende sempre do contexto. Acho que já ouvi todas as versões no dia-a-dia em contextos diferentes.

<sup>1 - Nas alíneas (a) e (e) as expressões têm o significado de "Eu trabalho sozinho amanhã."</sup>

Comment: É claro que se mudas as frases, os significados são diferentes... "Só amanhã trabalho 12 horas" é uma frase completamente diferente de qualquer das apresentadas pelo OP.

Comment: @Artefacto "Só amanhã trabalho" está sim é o ponto (d) só que com outro significado aqui.